# Cucumber: How to get scenario step parameters from a file?

Tags: selenium, cucumber

Is there a way to get the Cucumber scenario steps parameters from a file?

For example lets say we've got two feature files, and each of them does an action on a button.

Feature1:  click "Button1"

Feature2:  assert visibility of "Button1"

Now lets say I want both features to test "Button2" INSTEAD on "Button1".
It will be easy if the button parameter could be stored in a conf file or something, so that I won't need to change the code.

Is it possible?

Comment: What are you using along with cucumber and selenium?

Comment: Jenkins run cucumber and selenium that test Java based web.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.